# What's wrong in my code for dictionary update by another method

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't understand what's the problem in the following code.

```
data = {
    'x' : [1,-3,0,-7,0,6,2,-1,0,10],
    'y' : [2,6,3,-4,7,9,3,-1,-100,10]
}

def updateCentroids(data,u_centroids,k):
    distance = {} 
    for i in u_centroids.keys():
        distance[i] = [(u_centroids[i][0] - data['x'][j])**2 + (u_centroids[i][1] - data['y'][j])**2 for j in range(len(data['x']))]
    cluster = []
    for i in range(len(data['x'])):
        c = { k : distance[k][i] for k in distance.keys() }
        cluster.append(min(zip(c.values(), c.keys()))[1])
    for key in u_centroids.keys():
        temp_x = [ data['x'][i] for i in range(10) if(cluster[i] == key)]
        u_centroids[key][0] = (sum(temp_x)/len(temp_x))
        temp_y = [ data['y'][i] for i in range(10) if(cluster[i] == key)]
        u_centroids[key][1] = (sum(temp_y)/len(temp_y))       
    return u_centroids

c = {
    1: [2,3],
    2: [1,2],
    3: [0,3]
}
print('old c')
print(c)
new_c = updateCentroids(data,c.copy(),3)
print('new_c')
print(new_c)
print('c')
print(c)
```

**My Output is**

```
old c
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 2], 3: [0, 3]}
new_c
{1: [6.0, 7.333333333333333], 2: [0.0, -33.0], 3: [-2.5, 3.0]}
c
{1: [6.0, 7.333333333333333], 2: [0.0, -33.0], 3: [-2.5, 3.0]}
```

In this code, I want to don't change `c`. The new updated value is stored in `new_c`, not in `c`.
In this code after updating the value by `updateCentroids` method, it also changed `c`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that [`dict.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20copy#dict.copy) only performs a shallow copy, so the lists within the copy of `c` still refer to the same lists as in `c`, and when you modify those lists, they modify the lists in `c` as well. You can work around this by using [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=copy%20deepcopy#copy.deepcopy) instead:

```
import copy
new_c = updateCentroids(data,copy.deepcopy(c),3)
```

Then your output is as desired:

```
old c
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 2], 3: [0, 3]}
new_c
{1: [6.0, 7.333333333333333], 2: [0.0, -33.0], 3: [-2.5, 3.0]}
c
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 2], 3: [0, 3]}
```